# How should I work in order to land a good internship or a good job in the big companies?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, design, user-research, jobs

I want tips from experts and people working in this field already. I wish to continue my career in UI/UX and would like to know what steps to take in order to land an internship or even a job in a good company so that I could start preparing. I'm currently doing my 3rd year of B.tech in CSE and have experience of working as a graphic designer for almost 3 years now.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @It's Dylan, this is not a UX Design question. But here you go, most places seeking UX/ UI Designers want to see your portfolio of work. Here are some suggestions:

1. With a CSE Experience, one place to position yourself strongly would be to code your own website showcasing your work.
2. Structure your projects in such a way that showcases your process, and an important thing to show and talk about in interviews is the challenges you ran into and how did you overcome them. UX Design is about solving problems, thus it is important to show the process.
3. Seek portfolio reviews. Every critique you get might not be useful, but will nonetheless give you a different viewpoint, and some suggestions will definitely help you improve. Also, take critique with humility, no one is perfect.
4. Listen to podcasts about cracking UX Design Interviews.
5. Reach out to people working at the 'good' companies in your list and understand what their hiring process is like. That way you can position yourself strongly, and even find out if that company is a good fit for you.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a UX question, any decent answer could essentially apply to job hunting in general. Expand your network, setup a blog/portfolio/website to help yourself standout, find the companies you're interested in working for and  learn about their business proactively.

You are in luck though I have some UX resources for you.

1. The folks at Las Vegas UX/UI are hosting an online event next Tuesday focused on UX Design Interviews https://hopin.to/events/hacking-the-design-interview
2. Nielsen Norman Group has a free report on UX Careers. It might not help you get your foot in the door but should help you think about your career long-term which will actually help you get it started. https://www.nngroup.com/reports/user-experience-careers/